# Laravel Eloquent apply search condition to all requests

Tags: laravel

In Laravel Eloquent, there is a concept called "Soft Deletes" where a record is "Deleted" from the database. It's not actually deleted, there is only a date added to the "deleted_at" field. This means that almost any request, other than those that specify searching for soft deleted records, will not return those records, even if they match the criteria of the original request.

Is there a way to do something similar for other values? For example, if I have a column in the table called "is_ready", no search request will return a record unless that record has "is_ready" set to true, even if all other conditions are met.

This is something that has to apply to all requests made though this model over a large quantity of different queries, so it's not feasible to add that condition to all queries individually.

Comment: Have a read of the documentation for Model Scopes (Global and Local): https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#query-scopes. IIRC, that is essentially what the `SoftDeletes` trait does, with some extra functionality via the applied Trait.

Comment: @TimLewis I will try it out, but that looks like exactly what I need. Thanks Tim.